# Excel Conditional Formatting when adding extra columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've created a worksheet and added conditional formatting to it. Unfortunately whenever I need to add extra columns to this sheet, my conditional formatting messes up. Not only the range when this needs to be applied but also if was previously one colour was applied to a certain condition into a cell, that colour remains there even if I delete the content of the cell and leave it empty. All I can do is to delete the rule that was previously applied there and start all over again. Now this gets REALLY annoying if I have many worksheets that need the same modification (added columns) and all have these same conditional formattings applied. Gets even more annoying if I need to add/delete columns on a regular basis. Is there something I can do so that this error doesn't occur anymore?

Comment: If you could share your file, or at least screenshot of the conditional formatting that would help to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the columns INSIDE your conditionally formatted range rather than appending right next to it. You can always just change where the conditional formatting rules applies to rather than deleting and recreating them altogether.